# How to filter a string in ansible using regex

Tags: regex, ansible

I'm using ansible to read a value and parse it

**Value**
link: hdfs:///test/test2

**The output should be**: /test/test2

**Ansible that is not working :**

- set_fact:
  my_var: "{{ link | regex_search('hdfs://'}}"
  delegate_to: localhost

Answer (score 1):

The task below does the job

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        my_var: "{{ link|regex_replace(_regex, _replace) }}"
      vars:
        _regex: '^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$'
        _replace: '/\2/\3'
```

gives

```yaml
  my_var: /test/test2
```

Simple split&join works too. The task below gives the same result

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        my_var: "/{{ link.split('/')[-2:]|join('/') }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like as follows

- basevariable should be set to `hdfs:///test/test2`

```yaml
- name: regex replace
  set_fact:
    final_var: "{{  basevariable | regex_replace(reg_search, reg_replace)  }}"
  tags:
    - reg-replace
```

[More info](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/replace_module.html)